# Nested foreach loop php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, foreach, laravel-blade

I have seen all the solutions on here, but just cant seem to understand it.

```
array (size=340)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[92]
      public 'name' => string 'page_fan_adds_unique' (length=20)
      public 'period' => string 'day' (length=3)
      public 'values' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => 
            object(stdClass)[93]
              public 'value' => int 0
              public 'end_time' => string '2016-07-01T07:00:00+0000' (length=24)
          1 => 
            object(stdClass)[94]
              public 'value' => int 0
              public 'end_time' => string '2016-07-02T07:00:00+0000' (length=24)
          2 => 
            object(stdClass)[95]
              public 'value' => int 0
              public 'end_time' => string '2016-07-03T07:00:00+0000' (length=24)
      public 'title' => string 'Daily New Likes' (length=15)
      public 'description' => string 'Daily: The number of new people who have liked your Page (Unique Users)' (length=71)
      public 'id' => string '1791907811022418/insights/page_fan_adds_unique/day' (length=50)
```

I can loop through the main array and echo the name, tittle & description, but cannot seem to access the values array.

I have written this inside the first foreach but throws an objtostring error

```
@foreach($value->values as $key)
                {{$key->value}}
            @endforeach
```

Im sure it is simple, would have done it easily in JS, but not so experienced in PHP, thanks for the help

```
<?php var_dump($value->values) ?>
```

tried dumping that it game me

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[93]
      public 'value' => int 0
      public 'end_time' => string '2016-07-01T07:00:00+0000' (length=24)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[94]
      public 'value' => int 0
      public 'end_time' => string '2016-07-02T07:00:00+0000' (length=24)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[95]
      public 'value' => int 0
      public 'end_time' => string '2016-07-03T07:00:00+0000' (length=24)
```

have tried a lot of things, still not able to loop through it.

**NEW UPDATE**

have converted it into json then looping through it and tried a dump.

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($value->values), True);
                    // var_dump($array);
                    for ($i=0; $i < count($array); $i++) { 
                            var_dump($array[$i]);
                    }
```

**result**

```
array (size=2)
  'value' => int 0
  'end_time' => string '2016-07-01T07:00:00+0000' (length=24)
array (size=2)
  'value' => int 0
  'end_time' => string '2016-07-02T07:00:00+0000' (length=24)
array (size=2)
  'value' => int 0
  'end_time' => string '2016-07-03T07:00:00+0000' (length=24)
```

how do i loop through this now to extract value & end_time ?

Comment: What template library are you using? `@foreach` and `@endforeach` are not native PHP

Comment: use laravel, can change it to native php as well, just need to understand how the loops work first.

Comment: What is "an objtostring error"?

Comment: should have copied down the error, my bad. Basically the error was saying i was trying to convert an object into a string.

Comment: have updated the post. just missing the last step

Comment: you are in right direction as your "value" have data Int 0 so php treat as false or empty i.e it is not displaying. did you tried  $array[$i]['end_time'] what is output. and for printing zero you need to do something like echo "$array[$i][value]"